# Ceiling fan to can lights

Tags: lighting

I want to remove a ceiling fan that is attached to a switch for the fan and a switch for the light.  Is it possible to: install can lights on one switch and a pendant light on the other switch by using the current wiring configuration of 1 white, 1 black, 1 red and one ground.

Comment: Yes.  If there was a switch that controlled the light, and another that controlled the fan. You have everything you need to switch two separate sets of lights.

Comment: Thanks, So do I simply connect new blacks to existing black in box and new white to white in the box  and the other new white to the exiting red in the box?

Comment: Are you in USA, UK, or somewhere else?

Comment: If you're in the USA, white goes to white.  Black goes to either black or red,  depending on which switch you want to control what.

Comment: USA: So my 2 new blacks will connect to the existing red and black, will both new whites connect to the same existing white? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what's going on, some photos might be helpful.  But yes, typically you'll connect the white from both lights to the white from the ceiling.  Then one black to black, and the other black to red.

Comment: @tester101 -- That's probably worth making an answer, with a few additional words about why we're making this assumption (US conventions of black as hot, red as alternate hot in this case used for the other switch, white as neutral) and "if in doubt, test".